# Azure Changes not getting published

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I have made changes to my css on my MVC5 project that are working as intended on my local version but when I deploy to Azure the changes are not working.

I have tried creating a min.css file but this did not work

Comment: You can start with [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues) to help isolate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a hard refresh and pulled a copy of the stylesheet from the server to see if the changes you made are actually there? Http caching could be the culprit depending on how you're packaging your CSS.

Next, check the page source to make sure that your page is actually requesting the stylesheet you think it is. For example, if your site is requesting styles.min.css but you only made changes to styles.css and didn't create a new minified version, that'll cause problems.

Third, I'd check the elements that do not have the styles you're expecting and trace the styles with something like Chrome Developer Tools to ensure that your styles aren't being overridden in a way you're not expecting.